# Testing a Socket.io app, in which two connections interact

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, mocha.js

I'm very new to unit testing for NodeJS, right now i want to test a socket.io server using Mocha, the app involves the interaction of 2 sockets, the spec is the following

```
var expect = require('expect.js');
var io = require('socket.io-client');

describe("Server", function() {
    var options = {
        transports: ['websocket'],
        'force new connection': true
    };

    var socketOne;
    var socketTwo;

    it("Should do stuff", function(done) {

        socketOne = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

        socketOne.on("connect", function(data) {
            socketTwo = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

            socketTwo.on("connect", function(data) {
                console.log("hellow world");

            });
        });

        socketOne.on("connection", function(x) {
            console.log(x);
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

By now, i just want the test to create two socket connections, but when i run it, it seems that only the "socketOne" is connecting to server, the socketTwo.on("connection") doesn't get called. Do you know what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The socket.io client will recycle (multiplex) any existing connection, which is why your second one isn't firing the connect event. To prevent this, you can disable multiplex by specifying `{multiplex: false}` in the connect options. Like this:

```
socketOne = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

socketOne.on("connect", function(data) {
    socketTwo = io.connect("http://localhost:3000", {multiplex: false});

    socketTwo.on("connect", function(data) {
        console.log("hellow world");

    });
});
```